# I want to convert Python models list to Dictionary

Tags: python, angularjs, django, dictionary

This is the thing that I want to show...

```
taskNameList = Task.objects.all()
```

using angularJS, I want to to show this list to my template such as...

list.html

```
 <div ng-init="tasks = {{ taskNameList }} ">
```

I am sure this code isn't correct.

or should it be something like.

```
<div ng-init="tasks = [{{ taskNameList }}]">
```

I also tried this but it is not still showing up...

Comment: Did you try `tasks=taskNameList` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want **dictionaries in a list** use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

```
taskNameList = Task.objects.values()

>>> print(taskNameList)
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'i am the first task', ...}, ...]
```

If you want **tuples in a list** use [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
taskNameList = Task.objects.values_list()

>>> print(taskNameList)
[(1, 'i am the first task'), ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but I want to show it in template with angularJs

Comment: I don't know anything about angular-js but you can return `taskNameList` as JSON using [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) (`return JsonResponse(taskNameList, safe=False`).